# Python Django: initialize custom model variable based on related object

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to define a custom variable inside a django model class that depends on a related object. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
class Vm(models.Model):
    position = models.OneToOneField('Position', null=True, blank=True, default = None)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        models.Model.__init__(self)
        self.port = 5000+10*(self.position.position-1)

class Position(models.Model):
    position = models.IntegerField()
```

So when I initialize a Vm object, I want to access its 'port' attribute that depends on its related foreign key 'position'.

Vm object and corresponding Position object are already created and stored in DB. When I'm trying to initialize a Vm object `vm = Vm.objects.get(pk=1)` I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'position'` like the position object has not been initialized yet. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `position` is nullable, and if the value is `None`, you cannot access `position` attribute of `None`

One fix would be:

```
class Vm(models.Model):
    position = models.OneToOneField('Position', null=True, blank=True, default = None)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Vm, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)
        if self.position:
            self.port = 5000+10*(self.position.position-1) 
        else:
            self.port = 5000 #Or whatever the default you want to set.
```

Another approach:

```
class Vm(models.Model):
    position = models.OneToOneField('Position', null=True, blank=True, default = None)
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super(Vm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def port(self):
        if self.position:
            return 5000+10*(self.position.position-1)
        else:
            return 5000 #or any default value you wish to specify.
```

And whenever you want to access `port`, do

```
vm = Vm.objects.get(pk=1)
port = vm.port()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! just want to add that `super(Vm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` should be `super(Vm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`